# Appengine query seems to ignore one of my filters (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filter, datastore

I recently started working with Appengine, and everything has been going very smoothly up until this point. I've used up to two filters on a query many times, but with a third filter, the query seems to ignore one of my filters. It is always the same filter that gets ignored no matter what order I set the filters. The one being ignored is the "Room" filter.

Here is my code:

```
Query q = new Query("Schedule").setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("FranchiseKey", "Franchise(5)"))
            .setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("Room", "Room(81)"))
            .setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("Date", date));
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
    List<Entity> results = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

There are also entries in my datastore with "Room(82)", and this query returns those as well.

I was going to post a screenshot of my datastore, but it won't let me since this is my first post.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in dev or production.  If not dev make sure indexes have been built

Comment: I have tested it in both the dev environment and the production environment. Would indexes cause it to completely ignore a filter? I thought indexes just help the query to run faster.

Comment: are you getting any index not found exception? can you please post your model here.

Comment: If you add a property and index after the fact you will need to reindex preexisting records

Comment: I have never created indexes. I'm not getting any index not found exceptions. All my queries have worked before without setting up indexes. I believe this should at least still work without indexes being set up, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have created indexes and I'm still having this problem. All my queries with 2 or less filters work perfectly. It's only when I have 3 of more filters that the crap hits the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use .addFilter instead of .setFilter ?

Although addFilter is deprecated so it would be more appropriate to use setFilter with CompositeFilterOperator.and(filter ...)

Examples on: [Datastore Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) documentation.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use addFilter and I had the same problem.